# What is the name of this c# shorthand?

Tags: c#

I have seen the below code. I understand what it's doing. It gets a list of enum and then matches it with value passed and returns the matched one. What is this shorthand called? Is there a link a to more advanced short hands like this?

```
string a = null;
a = getListOfEnums()["matching value"];
```

Edit
It does not need to be an enum. It can be a dictionary object (key value pair) too.

Comment: Please put some more code in context of the Enum type. But as you have written your code, GetListOfEnums() should return keyvaluepairs of string and Actions. And this is not any kind of shorthand, but just a normal syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about the code? In current form the only way it may work is that `getListOfEnums()` returns a delegate that takes a `string` and returns a `string`. That wouldn't match name of the method, so I don't think that's the case.

What I think you're talking about is indexer:

```
string a = null;
a = getListOfEnums()["matching value"];
```

Comment: you might be right. i updated the code. I saw that code in vb initially. So used an online tool to covert it.

Comment: In VB `()` is used for indexers.

Comment: my bad. you are right, thanks.. are there any more advanced short hands like this?

Comment: Neither it's a shortcut not it's advanced. You should start with a C# tutorial to learn C# syntax better.